# Too many forms on a page - is it an issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am looking for the practice which is most advisable in terms of coding practice

I have a comment system which for each comment, you can reply to. This leads me to several options on implementing this (presume the backend is already created)

1. When the user clicks '`reply`', ajax is fired, getting the appropriate partial (including the authenitcation token, etc) and it inserts that into the appropriate place
2. I have a hidden form for each comment, and clicking `reply` will just make it visible
3. I use javascript to generate the form on the fly when the user click reply and insert it to the appropriate div where the reply was clicked

My problems with each is

for 1 - This causes requests, delay and I am not sure ajax is needed here

for 2 - Too many forms on the page.. Imagine thousands of comments so for each comment there will be a form which looks more or less the same

for 3 - I don't know if I can generate the authenticity token on the client

the form should look something like

```
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="comments/3/reply" data-remote="true" method="post">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="J0/asxkDH....vdlKLOUuQ9/TAxACWnZKdwy+c="></div>
                    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="tae" style="overflow: hidden;"></textarea>
                    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met a similar case before and I ended with an Ajax solution which is similar to your #1.

For #2, yes, there are too many forms, even if hidden. I don't like that.

For #3, I thought to use a JS template which is a popular style in Backbone. But, I did not find a mature and up to date jQuery templating solution at that time. I also didn't have enough time in that case, so I gave up.

*add:* For authenticity_token in #3, I have not tested that but I don't think this will be an issue if a form template has already been output into DOM with token ready. They are for same user and same type of object. We only need to change the object id or other minor things. One thing to notice is, you need to **reload the template by Ajax** once a successful Ajax request handled.

I think #1 is fine. There won't be too many Ajax requests. Users will only request a form when they need it, and the delay is too minimal to notice. I even set `sleep` to enhance the loading effect :) Besides, Basecamp also uses Ajax heavily to render dynamic things.

*P.S. Thanks for Leon to revise my grammar :)*